# using WPalchemy to output custom metabox from homepage template

Tags: metabox, templates, wpalchemy

I am new to php and I am using wpalchemy to create a custom metabox. I want to output the info from the metabox on a template page, not inside a loop. I have tried the following to no avail per the documentation on wpAlchemys site. Side note I want to create a custom metabox with the ability to upload multiple images is wpalchemy a good starting point to do this.

```
<?php
    global $custom_metabox;
    $custom_metabox->the_meta();
    $custom_metabox->the_field('name');
    $custom_metabox->the_value();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try specifying the ID of the post for which you need to get data from:

```
$custom_metabox->the_meta(101);
```

Comment: I Tried $custom_metabox->the_meta(2); based on my url /wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit to no avail

Comment: I am actually trying to do this with the image uploader tutorial off your site. The multiple image uploader metabox is working, but I don't know how to output it on my template